# Using ETGeoWizard functions in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, et-geowizards

I have ETGeo Wizard license and I would like to run the functions via ArcPy instead of running them in ArcMap.
However, the functions works in ArcMap but not  in a script.
one of the example is finding a center line of a polygon. I have got an error whenever run it in script. The error doesn’t make any sense because the function can take 6 arguments.
I have used even different names for the function as it used by other users.
 but still it doesn’t work.
I have ArcMap 11.6, Python 2.7 and ETGeo Wizard 11.6

Any suggestions?

```
BufferOutput = r'D:/Result/Segmented_Buffer.shp'
CenterLine =   r'D:/Result/Segmented_CenterLine.shp'
MAX_width = 1.0
MIN_width = 0.5
centerlines_type = "Inside"
smooth_centerlines = True
arcpy.ET_GPCreateCenterlines(BufferOutput, CenterLine, MAX_width, MIN_width, centerlines_type, smooth_centerlines)

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...../Convert Segment to Line.py", line 7, in <module>
arcpy.ET_GPCreateCenterlines(BufferOutput, CenterLine, MAX_width, MIN_width, centerlines_type, smooth_centerlines)
TypeError: ET_GPCreateCenterlines() takes no arguments (6 given)
Process finished with exit code 1


arcpy.CreateCenterlines(BufferOutput, CenterLine, MAX_width, MIN_width, centerlines_type, smooth_centerlines)

Error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../Convert Segment to Line.py", line 7, in <module>
arcpy.CreateCenterlines(BufferOutput, CenterLine, MAX_width, MIN_width, centerlines_type, smooth_centerlines)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CreateCenterlines'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you please include the error so we can help troubleshoot?

Comment: Have you looked at section D on this page? https://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/ETGW12UG_WEB/etgw/howtouseInArcGIS.htm It recommends creating your script in ModelBuilder but also shows the code for importing the tools--basically by adding the ETGeoWizard "toolbox"

Comment: @neuhausr yes I have seen it, but I have ETGeo Wizard version 11.6